# Selecicionar datos de un usuario logueado SQLite ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite, recyclerview, android-sqlite

Estoy realizando una app para reservar citas en una peluquería, y me gustaría que cuando ya me encuentre dentro de la aplicación (Usuario logueado), me muestre solo las citas de ese usuario logueado, y no de todos los usuarios que hayan pedido una cita en la aplicación. Lo muestro todo en un RecyclerView. Para la base de datos utilizo SQLite.

ListaCitasAdapter.class

```
public class ListaCitasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListaCitasAdapter.CitasViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Citas> listaCitas;

    public ListaCitasAdapter(ArrayList<Citas> listaCitas){
        this.listaCitas = listaCitas;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CitasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_item_citas,null,false);
        return new CitasViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CitasViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtTipoSesion.setText(listaCitas.get(position).getSesion());
        holder.txtFechaCita.setText(listaCitas.get(position).getFecha());
        holder.txtAgendaHora.setText(listaCitas.get(position).getFecha_agenda());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaCitas.size();
    }

    public class CitasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtTipoSesion,txtFechaCita,txtAgendaHora;
        public CitasViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtTipoSesion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTipoSesion);
            txtFechaCita = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtFechaReserva);
            txtAgendaHora = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtFechaHora);
        }
    }
}
```

DbCitas.class, donde hago el select con los datos que quiero mostrar

```
public class DbCitas extends SQLiteHelper {

    Context context;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public DbCitas(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<Citas> leerCitas(){
        SQLiteHelper con = new SQLiteHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = con.getReadableDatabase();

        ArrayList<Citas> lista_citas = new ArrayList<>();
        Citas citas = null;
        Cursor c = null;

        c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT servicio,fecha_reserva,agenda FROM reserva",null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            do {

                citas = new Citas();
                citas.setSesion(c.getString(0));
                citas.setFecha(c.getString(1));
                citas.setFecha_agenda(c.getString(2));

                lista_citas.add(citas);

            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }c.close();
        return lista_citas;
    }

}
```

VerCitas.class, aquí recojo las citas

```
public class VerCitas extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    SQLiteHelper con;
    ArrayList<Citas> listaCitas;
    RecyclerView lista_Citas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_citas);

        //Iniciamos conexión con la base de datos
        con = new SQLiteHelper(this);
         lista_Citas = findViewById(R.id.lista_citas);
         lista_Citas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

         DbCitas dbCitas = new DbCitas(VerCitas.this);


         listaCitas = new ArrayList<>();
         ListaCitasAdapter adapter = new ListaCitasAdapter(dbCitas.leerCitas());
         lista_Citas.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

Está es la tabla Reserva, y Usuario

```
 public static final String CREAR_TABLA_RESERVAR = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLA_RESERVA + " (" +
            USU_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
            RES_TIPO_SERVICIO + " TEXT, " +
            RES_FECHA + " TEXT UNIQUE, " +
            RES_AGENDA + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
            " FOREIGN KEY (" +USU_EMAIL + ") REFERENCES " + TABLA_USUARIOS + "(" + USU_EMAIL + "));";

}

public static final String CREAR_TABLA_USUARIOS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLA_USUARIOS + " (" +
            USU_USUARIO + " TEXT UNIQUE, " +
            USU_NOMBRE_APELLIDOS + " TEXT, " +
            USU_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, " +
            USU_CONTRASEÑA + " TEXT, " +
            USU_TELEFONO + " TEXT UNIQUE)";
```

Comment: En tu función leerCitas() está leyendo todo. En la sentencia SQL has de añadir la cláusula WHERE para escoger sólo las citas que cumplan la condición, en tu caso las que sean igual al usuario.

Comment: Ahora no me muestran resultados :(, me podrías mostrar como harías la consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he conseguido solucionar mediante el uso de SharedPreferences.
DbCitas.class

```
public ArrayList<Citas> leerCitas(){

        SQLiteHelper con = new SQLiteHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = con.getReadableDatabase();

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("email", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String email = sharedPref.getString(context.getString(R.string.correo), "");

        String[] parametros = { email };
        String[] campos = {TablasBD.RES_TIPO_SERVICIO,TablasBD.RES_FECHA,TablasBD.RES_AGENDA};


        ArrayList<Citas> lista_citas = new ArrayList<>();
        Citas citas = null;
        Cursor c = null;

        try {

           c = sqLiteDatabase.query(TablasBD.TABLA_RESERVA,
                   campos,
                   TablasBD.USU_EMAIL + " = ? ",
                   parametros,
                   null,
                   null,
                   TablasBD.RES_FECHA);

            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                while (c.moveToNext()){
                    citas = new Citas();
                    citas.setSesion(c.getString(0));
                    citas.setFecha(c.getString(1));
                    citas.setFecha_agenda(c.getString(2));

                    Log.i("Sesión", citas.getSesion());
                    Log.i("Fecha", citas.getFecha());

                    lista_citas.add(citas);

                                    }
                c.close();

        }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }return  lista_citas;

    }
```